# Filtering EventTypes

Tags: opc-ua, opc, milo

Im trying to receive events from specific event types only. The idea is to then create a custom Eventfilter for each available EventType on the server, allowing to receive EventType specific properties only. But once I implement a Contentfilter (where clause), no events are received anymore.

In this example I would like filter out all events except BaseEvents. Does anybody know how to write a correct Contentfilter for that? Thank you in advance.

```
EventFilter eventFilter = new EventFilter(
            new SimpleAttributeOperand[]{
                new SimpleAttributeOperand(
                    Identifiers.BaseEventType,
                    new QualifiedName[]{new QualifiedName(0, "EventId")},
                    AttributeId.Value.uid(),
                    null)
            },
            new ContentFilter(new ContentFilterElement[]{
                new ContentFilterElement(
                    FilterOperator.Equals,
                    new ExtensionObject[]{
                        ExtensionObject.encode(client.getSerializationContext(),  
                            new SimpleAttributeOperand(
                                Identifiers.BaseEventType,
                                new QualifiedName[]{new QualifiedName(0, "BaseEventType")},
                                AttributeId.Value.uid(),
                                null))
                    }
                )
            })
        );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is all that is wrong, but for one thing the BrowseName of the variable holding the event type is "EventType", not "BaseEventType", so your `SimpleAttributeOperand` is targeting the wrong property.

Second, The Equals operator is going to expect 2 operands (what is it comparing the value of "EventType" to?). So you need another operand that is just the NodeId of BaseEventType (so probably a `LiteralOperand` containing a `Variant` that contains `Identifiers.BaseEventType`).

So possibly something like this:

```java
ContentFilter contentFilter = new ContentFilter(new ContentFilterElement[]{
    new ContentFilterElement(
        FilterOperator.Equals,
        new ExtensionObject[]{
            ExtensionObject.encode(
                client.getStaticSerializationContext(),
                new SimpleAttributeOperand(
                    Identifiers.BaseEventType,
                    new QualifiedName[]{new QualifiedName(0, "EventType")},
                    AttributeId.Value.uid(),
                    null
                )
            ),
            ExtensionObject.encode(
                client.getStaticSerializationContext(),
                new LiteralOperand(new Variant(Identifiers.BaseEventType))
            )
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: Yes its working now!! Unfortunately cant upvote your comment because my account is new. I read so many helpful comments from you already. Truly appreciate your work. Thank you!